# single id alerting same time in a while loop

Tags: javascript, php

I am having a table from where i am fetching activities and displaying in a table ...like this

```
<table width="1000px;" style="border:0px;" >
    <tr>
        <?php
            $sql_activities="select * from tb_activities";
            $query_activities=mysql_query($sql_activities);
            while($row_activities=mysql_fetch_array($query_activities))
            {
        ?>
        <td width="50">
            <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $row_activities['activity_name']; ?>" name="activities" onclick="hi() " id="activities" /><?php echo " ".$row_activities["activity_name"]; ?></td>
            <?php    
            } 
            ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now i have applied it in an onlick event of a radio button and the script for the function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hi()
{
    a = document.getElementById("activities").value;
    alert(a);
}

</script>
```

i want to alert the name of the activity chosen but when i click on any activity, it shows the same. The first activity.ven if i have clicked on any other activity...can anyone help me ??

Comment: You can't give the same id to more than one element. And anyway, you don't have any relation between the clicked element and the one you alert.

Comment: document.getElementById only returns 1 element, you shouldn't give the same ID to all elements.. you can use classes, than iterate over them

Comment: so how can i solve this problem that i have mentioned above??

Comment: why does no one use template systems like smarty anymore...or using ajax to get data from php. getting kind of worried about seeing people mixing logic-code with representation-code that often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you should do is change this:

```
onclick="hi()"
```

to this:

```
onclick="hi(this);
```

then your function would be:

```
function hi(who) {
    var a = who.value;
    alert(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP side of things change:

```
<td width="50"><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $row_activities['activity_name']; ?>" name="activities" onclick="hi() " id="activities" /><?php echo " ".$row_activities["activity_name"]; ?></td>
```

To: ( YOU NEED Unique IDs on Input/ Radio Buttons to be generated dynamically & Sent to JS)

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<td width="50"><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $row_activities['activity_name']; ?>" name="<?php echo $row_activities['activity_name'].$i; ?>" id ="<?php echo $row_activities['activity_name'].$i; ?>" onclick="hi("<?php echo $row_activities['activity_name'].$i; ?> ")" /></td>
<?php $i++; ?>
```

In Javascript Change to This:

```
function hi(elementID) {
    var value = document.getElementById(elementID).value;
    alert(value);
}
```

Code may have some escape errors, but logically this should give you idea how to do it, Hope that helps.